# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64

Tags: java, spring, postman, jdbctemplate, spring-restcontroller

I am getting this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64` while calling the spring restfull request from the `POSTMAN` repeatedly.

I am using the GET method on method like this:

```
@RestController
public class SchedulerController{

    @Autowired
    private ReportScheduler reportScheduler;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/utilizationReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private void saveCompany() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException{       
        System.out.println("Hi");
        reportScheduler.methodC();      
    }

}
```

DAO Class(Implementation of methodC):

```
@Repository
@EnableScheduling
public class ReportScheduler {

    Configuration hbaseConfig;

    @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplatePOSTGRESQL")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplateDRILL")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateDrill;

    @Scheduled(cron="0 21 11 ? * *")
    public void methodC() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException {
        hbaseConfig = DbCon.connectHBase();
        String sql="select DISTINCT websocket_key from iot.sensor_configuration where sensor_type='Energy'";      
        List<Map<String,Object>> queryForList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (Map<String, Object> map : queryForList) {
            i++;
            String websocket_key=(String) map.get("websocket_key");
            Date date = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String yestDate = sdf.format(date);
            yestDate="2017-01-26";
            insertDataAtNight(websocket_key, yestDate,i);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void insertDataAtNight(String webscoket_key,String yestDate,int i){
        System.out.println("Inside");
        List<Map<String,Object>> queryForList=null;
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        Double totalenergy=0.0;
        String websocket_key=null;
        String datetime=null;
        String date=null;
        try
        {
            String sql = ""
                + "SELECT CONVERT_FROM(row_key, 'UTF8') AS row_key, "
                + "CONVERT_FROM(iot_energy_table.details.energy, 'UTF8') AS energy, "
                + "CONVERT_FROM(iot_energy_table.details.websocket_key, 'UTF8') AS websocket_key, "
                //+ "CONVERT_FROM(iot_energy_table.details.updated_time, 'UTF8') AS date, "
                + "CONVERT_FROM(iot_energy_table.details.updated_time, 'UTF8') AS updated_time FROM hbase.iot_energy_table "
                + "where iot_energy_table.details.websocket_key='"+webscoket_key+"' AND iot_energy_table.details.updated_time BETWEEN '"+yestDate+" 00:00:01' AND '"+yestDate+" 23:59:59' AND iot_energy_table.details.energy <> 'Nan' ";
                //+ "order by iot_energy_table.details.updated_time DESC limit 1";
            queryForList= jdbcTemplateDrill.queryForList(sql);
            for (Map<String, Object> map : queryForList) {
                String energy=map.get("energy").toString();
                websocket_key=map.get("websocket_key").toString();
                datetime=map.get("updated_time").toString();
                String a[]=datetime.split(" ");
                date=a[0];
                totalenergy=totalenergy+Double.parseDouble(energy);
                list.add(energy);
            }
            Double startEnergy=0.0;
            Double endEnergy=0.0;
            if(!list.isEmpty()){
                startEnergy=Double.parseDouble(list.get(0));
                endEnergy=Double.parseDouble(list.get(list.size()-1));
            }
            else
            {
                startEnergy=0.0;
                endEnergy=0.0;
            }
            Double energyConsumed=endEnergy-startEnergy;

            String sql1 = ""
                   + "INSERT INTO iot.energy_report( "
                   + "             websocket_key, updated_time, "
                   + "             energy_consumed_per_day) "
                   + "    VALUES (?, ?, "
                   + "             ?)";
            int update = jdbcTemplate.update(sql1,new Object[]{webscoket_key,yestDate,energyConsumed});


            HTable energyPacket = new HTable(hbaseConfig, "iot_energy_report");
            try
            {
                Put data = new Put(Bytes.toBytes((yestDate+(i)).toString() + ""));
                data.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("websocket_key"),
                       Bytes.toBytes(webscoket_key.toString()));
                data.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("updated_time"),
                       Bytes.toBytes(yestDate.toString()));
                data.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("energy_consumed_per_day"),
                       Bytes.toBytes(energyConsumed.toString()));
                energyPacket.put(data);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* 
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
    }
    */
}
```

This is the response i am getting in the POSTMAN:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
            <pre>java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:457)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:434)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:315)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2380)
    com.trinity.login.util.DbCon.connectHBase(DbCon.java:47)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.ReportScheduler.methodC(ReportScheduler.java:48)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.SchedulerController.saveCompany(SchedulerController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:455)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:434)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:315)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2380)
    com.trinity.login.util.DbCon.connectHBase(DbCon.java:47)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.ReportScheduler.methodC(ReportScheduler.java:48)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.SchedulerController.saveCompany(SchedulerController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:897)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.&lt;init&gt;(HConnectionManager.java:694)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:455)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:434)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:315)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2380)
    com.trinity.login.util.DbCon.connectHBase(DbCon.java:47)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.ReportScheduler.methodC(ReportScheduler.java:48)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.SchedulerController.saveCompany(SchedulerController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: apachehadoopmaster1
    org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:418)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:231)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:125)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(RetryInvocationHandler.java:73)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(RetryInvocationHandler.java:64)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:147)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.&lt;init&gt;(DFSClient.java:510)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.&lt;init&gt;(DFSClient.java:453)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.&lt;init&gt;(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.&lt;clinit&gt;(ProtobufUtil.java:201)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:897)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.&lt;init&gt;(HConnectionManager.java:694)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:455)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:434)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:315)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2380)
    com.trinity.login.util.DbCon.connectHBase(DbCon.java:47)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.ReportScheduler.methodC(ReportScheduler.java:48)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.SchedulerController.saveCompany(SchedulerController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.net.UnknownHostException: apachehadoopmaster1
    org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:418)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:231)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:125)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(RetryInvocationHandler.java:73)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(RetryInvocationHandler.java:64)
    org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:147)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.&lt;init&gt;(DFSClient.java:510)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.&lt;init&gt;(DFSClient.java:453)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.&lt;init&gt;(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.&lt;clinit&gt;(ProtobufUtil.java:201)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:897)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.&lt;init&gt;(HConnectionManager.java:694)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:455)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:434)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:315)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:2380)
    com.trinity.login.util.DbCon.connectHBase(DbCon.java:47)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.ReportScheduler.methodC(ReportScheduler.java:48)
    com.trinity.admin.scheduler.SchedulerController.saveCompany(SchedulerController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 logs.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the exception printing in the console:

```
Jan 27, 2017 12:09:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseHeader(InternalInputBuffer.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseHeaders(InternalInputBuffer.java:271)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1007)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From the postman this is the request i am using for calling the request:

```
https://localhost:8080/IoTRemotemonitoring/utilizationReport
```

Please suggest me what mistake i have done here.

Comment: Post your full stack trace. And the contents of `methodC()`.

Comment: I have added the full implementation above, Thank you.

Comment: Still no stack trace.

Comment: I have posted the full request above.

Comment: I don't see the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` anywhere.

Comment: There is ***No*** array index out of bounds exception in your stack trace

Comment: I have updated the console log above.Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Tried to google "apache coyote ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" gave me this as first result:  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59089

Comment: Can you show us which was the exact line where ArrayIndexOutOfBounds was thrown? Your code has no line numbers and we need to know where the error occurs in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be https protocol. Do you have https configured on your apache instance?

Bear in mind the original exception is being thrown due to:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: apachehadoopmaster1
```

Take a look to @adrianshum's comment. It could be that apache bug. You are using one of the version affected Apache Tomcat/7.0.62.